# MQTT: Mosquitto Broker and Sparkplug TCK

Tags: networking, mqtt, iot, mosquitto, mqtt-sparkplug

I would like to run the Sparkplug TCK using the Mosquitto broker (rather than HiveMQ as in the instructions).
I have enabled websockets on port 9001 in mosquitto.conf for this purpose, but when I try to access my broker on the corresponding port in the Sparkplug TCK web console, it seems as if the connection is established and then reset.
The error message I get is as follows: Client  disconnected due to malformed packet.
So there must be something wrong with the packets when establishing the connection.
However, a test using the MQTT Explorer application over the websocket was successful.

I would be very grateful if someone with experience could help me.

Thanks in advance,
SNC

---

mosquitto.conf:

```
listener 1883
listener 9001
protocol websockets
socket_domain ipv4
allow_anonymous true
```

---

Sparkplug TCK:

```
 Broker URL: {broker.ip.address.110]
 Broker Port: 9001
 Broker Endpoint: /mqtt
 Client Id: tck-web-console
```

## Addendum:

I was now able to connect the Mosquitto broker to the Sparkplug Test Compatibility Kit via websocket.
Unfortunately, the tests are not running.
If anyone has other experiences, please leave a comment, or if there are other brokers that the Sparkplug TCK works with..
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend to use mosquito. Single thread and single core. Especially with sparkplug message manipulation, when the payload is being handled all the other connections are waiting for the handshakes . And with TLS mosquito MQTT broker loses it's wings. Also the configuration is not best procedure.
Try using for instance Coreflux.
It is multi thread and low profile in memory, unless you use the hub to configure the broker.
The broker starts with a user root and password coreflux, you just need to enter the page and use MQTT topic
$SYS/Coreflux/Command

[Configure Coreflux MQTT Broker](https://docs.coreflux.org/getting-started/config-hubless/)

Comment: thanks for the tip i will check it out